# How to group a list of dictionaries with groupby from itertools?

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql, python-itertools

I am creating an application with python and I am using a postgresql database, and tortoise-orm for the queries.
In the database there are several tables, but for the problem in question I have: "project", "assignment". With a one-to-many relationship between them.
I need to filter the "assignments" according to a certain parameter (it doesn't matter for the question) and then I want to group them to return them in the json. This is the function that I am implementing:

```
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby

from app.models.assignment import Assignment

async def calendar(self, start_filter: date, final_filter:date):
        assignments = await self.model.filter(
            start_date__lte=final_filter,
            final_date__gte=start_filter
        ).prefetch_related("collaborator__job", "project").all()
        grouped_assignments = {}
        for project_id, project_assignments in groupby(assignments, lambda x: x.project_id):
            grouped_assignments[project_id] = list(project_assignments)
        return grouped_assignments
```

To get right to the problem, in assignments the filter is applied and I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "tarea de backend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-10",
    "final_date": "2023-02-20",
    "id": 1,
    "collaborator_id": 1,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de backend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-10",
    "final_date": "2023-02-25",
    "id": 2,
    "collaborator_id": 2,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de data science",
    "start_date": "2023-02-10",
    "final_date": "2023-02-20",
    "id": 3,
    "collaborator_id": 3,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de data science",
    "start_date": "2023-02-10",
    "final_date": "2023-02-25",
    "id": 4,
    "collaborator_id": 4,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de frontend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-20",
    "final_date": "2023-02-25",
    "id": 5,
    "collaborator_id": 5,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de frontend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-20",
    "final_date": "2023-02-25",
    "id": 6,
    "collaborator_id": 5,
    "project_id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de frontend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-20",
    "final_date": "2023-02-27",
    "id": 7,
    "collaborator_id": 6,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tarea de frontend",
    "start_date": "2023-02-20",
    "final_date": "2023-02-27",
    "id": 8,
    "collaborator_id": 6,
    "project_id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Tarea de backend",
    "start_date": "2023-03-11",
    "final_date": "2023-03-17",
    "id": 9,
    "collaborator_id": 1,
    "project_id": 2
  }
]
```

Right now there are only two projects (Project_id=1, and Project_id =2).
What I want is that all the tasks are grouped according to each project_id, so in the json I expect something like this:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "start_date": "2023-02-20",
      "collaborator_id": 6,
      "final_date": "2023-02-27",
      "id": 7,
      "name": "tarea de frontend",
      "project_id": 1
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "start_date": "2023-02-20",
      "collaborator_id": 6,
      "final_date": "2023-02-27",
      "id": 8,
      "name": "tarea de frontend",
      "project_id": 2
    },
    {
      "start_date": "2023-03-11",
      "collaborator_id": 1,
      "final_date": "2023-03-17",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Tarea de backend",
      "project_id": 2
    }
```

]
}

Actually the above json is what I am getting. For some reason I don't get all the assignments for each project (the date filter I'm testing returns the list with the 9 assignments I put above)
The way I see the code, in the for loop I am iterating through the assignments and grouping them by their project_id, group_by should only return two groupings, one for project_id=1 and the other for project_id=2, but it seems to be doing different groupings for the same project_id. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm misunderstanding how groupby works.

UPDATE:

```
async def calendar(self, start_filter: date, final_filter:date):
        assignments = await self.model.filter(
            start_date__lte=final_filter,
            final_date__gte=start_filter
        ).prefetch_related("collaborator__job", "project").all().values()
        assignments_data = jsonable_encoder(assignments)
        assignments = sorted(assignments_data, key=lambda x:x["project_id"])
        grouped_assignments = {}
        for project_id, project_assignments in groupby(assignments, lambda x: x["project_id"]):
            project_group = {}
            for job_id, job_assignments in groupby(project_assignments, lambda x: x.collaborator.job_id): #  here
                project_group[job_id] = list(job_assignments)
            grouped_assignments[project_id] = list(project_group)
        return grouped_assignments
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the last loop apply a sort to "assigments" like this:

```py
assignments = sorted(assignments, key=lambda x:x["project_id"]) # add this line
grouped_assignments = {}
for project_id, project_assignments in groupby(assignments, lambda x: x["project_id"]):
    grouped_assignments[project_id] = list(project_assignments)
```

Also i switch `x.project_id` to `x["project_id"]`

Comment: That works!... but unfortunately it causes me another problem hehe. assignments isn't exactly a list of dictionaries, it's a query that filters the assignments and returns a "Queryset". I could easily turn it into a dictionary, but then I can stop interacting with the object as I show in the code... and I need this since after I have to group them by "job_id" and the relationship between job and project is not direct, each job has some collaborators (hence the part of prefetch_related("collaborator__job", "project").all()).

Comment: If you look at the question in the new thing that I have put under "update", in the line where the comment "here" is, it will not work because I will be manipulating a dictionary, not an object.
Do you have any idea that can help me? Why do I have to order the assignments before doing groupby?